# What is the process of making a chracter creator like black desert in godot/unity?

Tags: graphics-programming, character

[example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qy-K8RYYE-k)

I get the point of switching heads or other body part models as long as they are all attached to the same bones then the animations will work, but what about changing the color of lips, eyelashes, skin, armor? those games don't have 100 different UV per model, they only have the body UV, the head one, the eye UV so 3 at most since the armor UV replaces the body UV

Plus those types of games also give access to momentary bones that change the shape of the mesh giving almost complete control over shaping a character, it not something new, Tera and Aion did it back in 2006-2007.

it's actually very common in Eastern games but almost no one does it for western games, I can't even find any tutorial that goes in depth into this or someone working on it at least showcasing the workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but what about changing the color of lips, eyelashes, skin, armor? those games don't have 100 different UV per model, they only have the body UV, the head one, the eye UV so 3 at most since the armor UV replaces the body UV

You can change the colors with shaders, controlled by shader parameters (I mean: uniforms).

For example, have the shader add a color only in areas defined by a texture (you can have additional textures and query them with the same UVs).

Since you only need one channel as mask to decide where to apply a color, you can define multiple areas in the same texture by using the different color channels. Furthermore the value of the channel can control intensity of the color.

You might want to have the base color be gray-scale, and apply the color by multiplication. So you change the hue and saturation, but keep the brightness of the base color gray-scale.

*You might also be interested in doing hue rotation in shader.*

It is also common that different cloth pieces reuse are the same mesh and same UV but with different texture (taking advantage of alpha transparency and scissors).

Also be aware that you can have bone attachments. I mean, other meshes that follow the transformation of the bones but are not part of the character mesh. Which you can use for armor, weapons and accessories.

---

> Plus those types of games also give access to momentary bones that change the shape of the mesh giving almost complete control over shaping a character, it not something new, Tera and Aion did it back in 2006-2007.

No momentary bones. Don't change the skeleton structure in runtime. However you can have extra bones in the skeleton that are not used by the animation. Yet you can allow these extra bones to deform the mesh, and you can allow the player to pose them.

Be aware that your animations won't work (well or at all) if you have a different skeleton. So even allowing the player to stretch the bones is problematic. If you need to support something like that you will need a proper animation retargeting solution.

However, I suspect what you are referring to is something else: have multiple base meshes (all with the same vertex count and topology), and  <strike>combine</strike> interpolate them linearly by weights controlled by the player (with sliders). This modifies the mesh (moves the vertex around), not the skeleton. *See also blend shapes.*